# remove a '\n' from a program

Tags: c, system, newline

```
system(do_this); // which executes an external program to output a phrase on the screen
printf("=My taxes");
```

Output:

> 500$
>
> =My taxes

Expected output:

> 500$=My taxes

I don't have control over the code executing in `do_this` which automatically outputs the `'\n'`.

Comment: Not in a standard way, there isn't. Perhaps with some specific console functions, but those are not part of C or its standard library.

Comment: Don't use `system()`, but rather `popen()` or something like that so you can capture the output and process it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
system("program | tr -d '\012\015'");
printf("=My taxes\n");
```

where *program* is the program you want to run. The `tr` command removes all CR and LF characters (codes 015 and 012 octal) from *program*'s output. The solution assumes *program* only outputs one line (your tax) and it works on systems with line endings CR, LF, CR+LF, LF+CR (includes all widely used operating systems like MacOS, Linux and Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change you system call to make use of utils to strip the newline

Rather that your system call being

```
system("a.out");
```

Change it to

```
system("a.out | awk '{ printf(\"%s\",$0); }'");
```